# How do I specify I want my project to depend on ALL subspecs in Cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods, react-native

React Native specifies many subspecs: `Core`, `RCTPushNotification`, `RCTNetwork` etc.

If you write

```
pod `React`
```

into a Podfile, then Cocoapods will only fetch `Core`, because [the podspec specifies React/Core as the default subspec](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.8.0-rc/React.podspec#L22).

How do I specify that ALL subspecs should be included, without me having to list them all!?

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of CocoaPods.
The React Podspec is purposely not including everything.

There is a default subspec for iOS Linking:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'ReactPod' do
pod 'React/RCTLinkingIOS'
end

target 'ReactPodTests' do
end
```

The question your are asking is discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/636) among other places.

Comment: So basically you're saying there's no way to do it, because it's by design. Fair enough.

But I'm confused as to what `RCTLinkingIOS` is, and how it's relevant to this question.  Did you just mean to use it as an example?